# Angular with signalR: Multiple hubconnections to the same route

Tags: angular, angular5, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-2

I have my client code as below. I have a signalr route and hub connection name. I am able to connect to the hub and get events. Now I need to connect to one more hub for the same route to get more events.

```
  this.hubConnection = this.window.$.hubConnection();
    this.hubConnection.url = this.apiUrl  + "api/signalr";
    this.hubProxy = this.hubConnection.createHubProxy("Event1Hub");
    this.hubProxy = this.hubConnection.createHubProxy("Event2Hub"); // When I add this line it is overriding first hub and only connecting to Event2Hub.
```

I am using     "signalr": "2.3.0",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a proxy for `Event1Hub` and then reassining that object instance with proxy for `Event2Hub`. If you want to communicate with both hubs you'll have to initialize separate proxy objects in order for this to work.

```
this.hubConnection = this.window.$.hubConnection();
this.hubConnection.url = this.apiUrl  + "api/signalr";
this.hubEvent1Proxy = this.hubConnection.createHubProxy("Event1Hub");
this.hubEvent2Proxy = this.hubConnection.createHubProxy("Event2Hub");
```

This way `hubEvent1Proxy` will provide `Event1Hub` communication while `hubEvent2Proxy` will provide `Event2Hub` communication.